# SQL choose data structure during creating index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, data-structures

May I know if there is any way to specify the data structure (B tree, hash table, R-tree etc.) of an index in a SQL (specifically SQL Server 2014)?

When I google it, I can only find the following syntax.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thank you!

```
CREATE INDEX name_index
ON table_name (Column_Name, Column_name2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The various types of index, use and the underlying structures are documented here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175049(v=sql.120).aspx

Summary: Clustered and non-clustered on-disk indexes are B-Trees, Memory only indexes can be Hash based. Columnstore indexes differ again in their structure. (Not to mention Spatial, XML and Full Text indexes)

Comment: Follow up question:  If I use "CREATE  INDEX index_name
 ON table_name (column_name)", will this use default index, which is clustered index (B tree)?

Comment: Aaah things change =). Used to be only B-Trees, but with in-memory tables apparantly a HASH index can be defined. This trades memory for performance (naturally). Note that in-memory tables are only supported from SQL Server 2014+.

Comment: @Chubaka The type of INDEX (hash or B-Tree) depends on the type of table: memory-optimized or disk-based. You can only have a HASH based index for memory-optimized tables by specifying it explicitely when creating an INDEX (`NONCLUSTERED HASH`). See [CREATE TABLE Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174979%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) for more details.